# How to pass integer array into IN clause?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to pass an integer array from input parameters of my postgresql function into sql IN clause.

Into what and how I can convert such array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had same problem lately.

Look here:

http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/Using-PL-pgSQL-text-argument-in-IN-INT-INT-clause-re-post-td3235644.html

Hope it helps.

Here is a sample function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "GetSetOfObjects"(ids text)
  RETURNS SETOF record AS
$BODY$select *
from objects
where id = any(string_to_array($1,',')::integer[]);$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE
```

Comment: How do you negate it, to find ids *NOT* in the array? Simply using != doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Cerin :please use `!= all` instead of `!= any`

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can't. What you *can* do is pass in a comma-delimited list and split it apart in your function. [Here are some examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594651/tsql-function-split-string) using SQL Server, but I'm sure they can be translated.

Unless [this (PostgreSQL)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/xfunc-sql.html#AEN46015) is what you're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

i usually use implicit conversion

select '{1,2,3,4,5}' :: integer[]

Comment: Question was not about how to get integer array ) I have such array by default from input params.